# Why ScanStreamTransformer is not return anything

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I'm not sure which part of my code is wrong. I can't receive anything inside of my `ScanStreamTransformer`, as you can see in the code below here inside  `_itemsTransformer()` I returned `ScanStreamTransformer` and I expected the print inside `ScanStreamTransformer` work or return the cache, but It does not work.

```
class CardBloc {
  final _repo = Repository();
  final _tIds = PublishSubject<List<int>>();
  final _itemsOt = BehaviorSubject<Map<int, Future<ItemModel>>>();
  final _itemsFt = PublishSubject<int>();


  Stream<List<int>> get topIds => _tIds.stream;
  Stream<Map<int, Future<ItemModel>>> get items => _itemsOt.stream;

  Function(int) get fetchItem => _itemsFt.sink.add;

  fetchIds() async {
    final ids = await _repo.fetchIds();
    _tIds.sink.add(ids);
  }

  CardBloc() {
    _itemsFt.stream.transform(_itemsTransformer()).pipe(_itemsOt);
  }

  _itemsTransformer() {

    return ScanStreamTransformer(
      (Map<int, Future<ItemModel>> cache, int id, index) {
        print('should be print!');

        cache[id] = _repo.fetchItem(id);
        return cache;
      },
      <int, Future<ItemModel>>{},
    );
  }

  dispose() {
    _tIds.close();
    _itemsOt.close();
    _itemsFt.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: seems there are no items in the `_itemsFt.stream` or nobody `listen()`s to `_itemsOt`

Comment: @pskink Thank you, I didn't insert all class of my code, I updated the question, I guess now is more clear, what I did

Comment: @pskink, you're right, I forgot to pass data to `fetchItem`, because that `_itemsFt.stream` has no data, thanks again for mention that

Comment: your welcome, btw why do you need `pipe` and that second `_itemsOt` stream?

Comment: Well, I'm new in Flutter. I watched some documents and tutorials, and then I thought it might be the best way to run `transformer` one time like this; I get the data from `_itemsFt`, then I send it to `transformer` then I send it to the `_itemsOt` after that, I send the data to each `StreamBuilder`..., and I'm still not sure this could be the best way or not but it works.

Comment: `transform()` method returns a `Stream` so you can use it directly without `pipe()`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I don't need the `_itemsOt `, I thought it might get an issue but I was wrong so yeah I used it directly, thank you again.

Comment: @Milad looks like you and me are following the same videos. I am stuck at the same point.  Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @pskink this is the reason for pipe
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b96352434c7db5a8321c6a77cfdd4a47

If you don't use pipe then transform leads to sort of like duplicate events. Which leads to an issue under some circumstances. 
Check above link. We have to avoid printing 1 multiple times. It should be printed just once.

Comment: @kapil, as @pskink mentioned the `_itemsFt.stream` has no items, so you should insert items inside it with `Function(int) get fetchItem` that created to pass data inside it and I used `fetchItem` inside `itemBuilder` in `ListView` widget  like `cardbloc.fetchItem(sps.data[item]);`.